# When I flag a question, does the user get notified or should I also post a comment?

Tags: discussion

E.g. I just flagged a question as off-topic because it's a serverfault.com question, should I add a comment suggesting they try serverfault.com, or is that superfluous?

Comment: No, they do not get notified, and yes a constructive and descriptive comment would be good.

Comment: If the plan is to eventually *migrate* the question, you really shouldn't leave a comment, because your comment will just cause the person to repost their question, then when the original eventually gets migrated…we end up with two questions.

Comment: Excellent point that wasn't picked up in the linked [duplicate] article.  Thanks.

Comment: @CodyGray There is no migration path from SO to SF.

Comment: Okay, then it's just general-purpose advice. That used to be one of the paths last time I looked, and I can't remember the last time I ever voted to migrate anything. I don't know why I needed to be notified of that fact.